# Farsi regular expression in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, farsi

I have this Python regular expression code in Python 3 that I do not understand. I appreciate any help to explain what exactly it does with a few examples. The code is this:

```
# encoding=utf-8
import re
newline = re.sub(r'\s+(((زا(ی)?)?|ام?|ات|اش|ای?(د)?|ایم?|اند?)[\.\!\?\،]*)', r'\1 ', newline)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is your regular expression:

```
\s+(((زا(ی)?)?|ام?|ات|اش|ای?(د)?|ایم?|اند?)[\.\!\?\،]*)
```

and here is a visualization:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/FQpHdKDXV6f2xjnt)

Your replacement is `r'\1 '` which means replace what you found with the 1st group followed by space. I don't read farsi, but here is another example:

```
\s+((a|b)[./?]*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/aptoXN2Cn8M8tNPM)

so let's execute some code:

```
>>> newline = '     a?    b?        a.'
>>> re.sub('\s+((a|b)[./?]*)', r'\1 ', newline)
'a? b? a. '
```

This eats extra spaces preceding a particular group of characters (the leading `\s+`) and changes it to the identified `group 1` followed by one space (`r'\1 '`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Based on the above figure, isn't the first group Group 1? Then what you said becomes confusing. Can you elaborate a little more please? For example if I have: `newline = 'رفته اند'`, what should I get after running the code?

Comment: provided your `newline` is unicode, you'd get the same thing, because there no extra spaces. `r'\1 '` will preserve everything in group 1 except the spaces.